# How can I use command usepackage in latex?

Tags: latex

While use command:

```
\usepackage{multicols}{2}
```

it shows errors. This also happens for adding of any type of `package`.

Why does this error occur?

Comment: When you call `\usepackage` don't add a second parameter. Just call `\usepackage{multicols}`. Also, try [TeX - Latex Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) for further Tex/LaTeX questions.

Comment: Did you use `\usepackage` in the preamble or inside the `document`?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   \usepackage{multicols} \begin{document}   ......... like this !! @Tom Solid

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to use `package` `multicol` and `environment` `multicols` (I guess). So:

```
%...
\usepackage{multicol}
%...
\begin{document}
  %...
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    %...
  \end{multicols}
  %...
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... its working ... thanks . @Tom Solid